# ggplot2 - changing or dropping specific legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a simple (maybe) question on ggplot2.

I would like to drop one of the variables in the legend, lets say `trt1` in the example below.

How do I do that? I would still like for it to be plotted just the variable should be removed from the legend.

Thanks for all your help!

Below is a simple example:

```
library(ggplot2)

bp <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot()

bp
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this. `scale_fill_discrete` is what you need:

```
library(ggplot2)

bp <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("ctrl","trt2"))

bp
```

[image]